# Share data between Watch app and iOS app in watchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I send a dictionary to an iOS app using:

```
- (void)sendMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message 
  replyHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler 
  errorHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError *error))errorHandler;
```

but I'm getting an error with this. I want to know how our parent app handle this request in watchOS2.

In watchOS1, I used `openParentApplication` to get data from the parent app, and `Appdelegate` had a `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` to handle that request. How do we handle this in watchOS2?

My Interface Controller:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context 
{
   [super awakeWithContext:context];
   if([WCSession isSupported])
   {
     self.watchSession = [WCSession defaultSession];
     self.watchSession.delegate = self;
     [self.watchSession activateSession];
   }
   [self sendRequestWithActionType:@"InitialView"];
}

-(void)sendRequestWithActionType:(NSString *)action
{
    NSDictionary *requst = @{@"request":action};
    [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:requst
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyHandler) {
                               [self setTextForLabelWithData:[replyHandler valueForKey:@"response"]];
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"");
                           }
 ];
}
```

Comment: You should be checking reachable before using sendMessage. What error do you get?

Comment: I want to get replyHandler dictionary.tell me what should I do in iOS app.I think,we should use  

     - (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary * __nonnull))replyHandler

give me an example for this

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of using sendMessage with a reply:

Sending side:

```
-(void)sendRequestWithActionType:(NSString *)action {
    NSDictionary *request = @{@"request":action};
    [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:request
                       replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyHandler) {
                           [self setTextForLabelWithData:[replyHandler valueForKey:@"response"]];
                       }
                       errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"");
                       }];
}
```

Receiving side:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *))replyHandler { 
    NSString *action = message[@"request"];
    NSString *actionPerformed;
    if ([action isEqual:@"foo"]) {
        // do "foo" stuff
        actionPerformed = @"foo done";
    } else if ([action isEqual:@"bar"]) {
        // do "bar" stuff
        actionPerformed = @"bar done";
    }
    replyHandler(@{@"actionPerformed":actionPerformed});
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to open the safari in iPhone when I click on some link in watch Application?

Comment: 1. You should mark my answer as the right one if it was helpful to you, 2. You are now asking a separate question which should probably be its own, 3. To answer it; no, that is not possible in unless the iOS app is foreground at that point in time

Comment: I didn't ask this question @ccjensen. Please answer my question if you have any idea.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450521/open-safari-ios-app-from-watch-app

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you weren't the originator of this one