# Open Safari iOS App from Watch App

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, watchkit, watchos-2

Is it possible to open the safari in iPhone when I click on some link in Apple watch Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if the iOS app happens to be running in the foreground. If you use the WatchConnectivity sendMessage API to wake the iOS app up in the background then you won't be able to open URLs and therefore not launch Safari.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any parent application in iOS

Comment: The only way to get a WatchApp in to the AppStore and on to someone's Apple Watch is with a parent iOS app containing it. How are managing to get it on to your own watch without a parent app?

Comment: I think it is not possible that you have an Apple Watch application and don't have it's iOS application. I have just created a watch application and Xcode created it's parent application itself. So thanks, now at least I can tell my client that parent application is required.

Comment: That's correct. Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem